# Firebase onAuthStateChanged signount infinite loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am facing infinite issue with firebase google signin ,I removed manually user from the firebase console.I tried many options such as unistalling app,removing google account still infinite loop persist.
  If I kept else of `updateUI` method blank ,I am landing on blank screen

```
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            Log.d(TAG,firebaseAuth.toString());
            if (firebaseUser != null) {
                user=new User(firebaseUser);
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + firebaseUser.getUid());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            updateUI(firebaseUser);
        }
    };

}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser firebaseUser){
    hideProgressDialog();
    if(firebaseUser!=null){
        saveUser();
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Else part executed");
        revokeAccess();
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
       // logout();
    }

}
```

Logs

```
09-04 11:36:06.824 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaft@327a804c
09-04 11:36:06.824 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
09-04 11:36:06.824 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: Else part executed
09-04 11:36:06.874 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaft@327a804c
09-04 11:36:06.874 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out
09-04 11:36:06.874 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: Else part executed
09-04 11:36:06.884 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: Revoking access
09-04 11:36:06.884 27913-27913/com.renteasy D/com.renteasy.views.activity.LoginActivity: Revoking access
```

Comment: is the loop really infinite or is it called twice?

Comment: yes it is in  infinite loop.. I don't understand how firebase persisting even after uninstall

Comment: Please post LoginActivity and SplashActivity